# Can i use hashicorp vault secret in single docker instance?

Tags: docker, vault, hashicorp

I've just setup ansible + hashicorp vault. The goal is to deploy docker container which will be managed by systemd service. When i deploy container via ansible, i can use hashi_vault module to keep sensitive data hidden. But i cant find a way to keep my envs hidden on bare docker (no swarm, no k8s, no compose).

My service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=postgres docker service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
TimeoutStartSec=0
Restart=on-abnormal
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker stop postgres
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm postgres
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull postgres:14.5-alpine3.16
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run \
--restart always \
--name postgres \
--env DB_PORT=5432 \
--env DB_USER=wikijs \
--env DB_PASS=wikijsrocks \
--env DB_NAME=wiki \
-v /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data  \
-p 5432:5432 \
postgres:14.5-alpine3.16

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I read an article about the vault agent, but still didn't understand if I could use it to transfer variables to a service file. If it is possible, please tell me exactly how to do it.

Comment: Given that you are using a Postgressql DB here, then you would probably want to use the Postgres secrets engine in Vault instead of (assuming here without further information) the KV2. Then the secrets are generated dynamically, and you do not need to place them in plain text like you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn't know that it was possible to use dynamic generation in Vault. 
In the example above, I need to connect a container with Wiki JS to a container with a Postgres database, so I need to somehow transfer connection settings to the wikijs.service file.

Comment: Oh yeah in that case you can probably use the `node-js` bindings inside the application.

Comment: To do that i should make my own docker image where i will integrate node-js bindings? Or add to dockerfile scripts, which will pull secrets from vault?
I was hoping there was some easier way to use secrets from vault on a bare docker.

Comment: Yeah if you want easy, then I think this will not be possible.